# Magento 2.1 Disconnection repeated when many users

Tags: magento2, admin

i created 10 account for the backend.
each user will be to able to place an order from the administration.

The problem is when there are more than three users connected at the same time, we often have sudden disconnections.

I have configured session_lifetime at 86400 but It has no effect.

Anyone have an idea?
Thanks

Comment: What kind of disconnections? Just being logged out suddenly?

Comment: Yes that's it with a error message : .Someone logged in to this account from another device or browser. Your current session is interrupted.

Comment: Have you checked everyone is using their individual account and not sharing? Could be having trouble there.

Comment: yes, everyone is using their account, it's sure.